# Connecting Microsoft Fabric Data Factory to an Azure repo - Pipelines Not Visible

Tags: azure-data-factory, microsoft-fabric

I have followed the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/admin/about-tenant-settings#how-to-get-to-the-tenant-settings on how to connect Data Factory from Microsoft Fabric Azure DevOps repo. I have successfully connected to Azure Repo but I'm not seeing any pipelines. Can someone let me know where I might be going wrong?

I am completely new to Microsoft Fabric

[image]

Comment: Hi there, By the `pipelines`, you mean Azure Data Factory pipelines not Azure DevOps pipelines right?

Comment: Hi @AlvinZhao, thanks for getting in touch. Yes I mean Azure Data Factory pipelines